# How to generate automatic email with username?

Tags: java, email

I am creating a web app.In that i have two registration forms .
a)Doctor    b)Patient

once the doctor & patient registered.The doctor has to send the notification to the patient.But the doctor won't like to send the notification from his personal mail .So how to generate the unique  email for the doctor  with our domain name ,So that when doctor sends the notification it shouldn't go with his personal  mail id ,it should go from his company,s email address.

or

if he gives his name  as username ,how to generate automatic email address with his username?

Comment: Prixanka, you have five questions with exactly 0 score. I think you should really really really read StackOverflows guide on how to write a question.

Comment: Did you face some technical problem while implementing this? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the mail address to be a valid mail address where mail can be received? If so, the answer to the question is dependent on the email system your domain uses. It may be very well possible that there is no easy automatic way to add a new email address and that adding an address requires manual work. Besides, who should receive the mails sent to the address? How do you ensure that the receiver will get the correct password to the mailbox? Or do you perhaps want a mail forwarding service where mails sent to "doctor12345@example.com" will go to the doctor's private address?

However, when sending mail do note that email addresses are not validated at all. It is trivial to forge sender addresses. Thus, you can generate the email address in the same way you can generate any string. For example, if the doctor has a unique id 12345, then you could generate "doctor" + 12345 + "@example.com".

Comment: Thanks for your kind assistence.

Comment: Like suppose doctor gave the perscription to the  patient .patient forget to take his pills at time .So the notification will go to the patient.The notification should automatically forward from the doctors  personal mail id to his company's mail id.

Comment: Doctor will send the notification to the patient .But the notification should not go through his personal mail id .The notification should go from his company's mail id.

Comment: Well, it looks like you need assistance about email systems. What system are you currently using? I think the correct place to ask about email systems is http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I donot know which system we are using .